# How to use a function pointer properly

Tags: c, function-pointers, typedef

I have problem with a function pointer. I have this typedef :

```
typedef struct patchwork *(*create_patchwork_value_fct) 
                                            (const enum nature_primitif);
```

which is generic for the sake of it (implemented in another file). I want to call it with an input. How do I do ?

Comment: This function pointer typedef works exactly the same as if you would do `typedef int* obscure_t; ...obscure_t ptr = &some_int;`

Answer (score 1):

You need to

1. Define a variable of the *type* of the `typedef`ed function pointer.
2. Put the address of a function having same signature to it.
3. Use the variable as a *normal* function name to make the function call.

Pseudo-code

If you have a function like

```
struct patchwork * funccall(const enum nature_primitif)
{
  //do something
}
```

and then, you can do

```
create_patchwork_value_fct fp= funccall;
struct patchwork * retptr = NULL;
enum nature_primitif enumVal = <some enum value>;

retptr = fp(enumVal);
```

Maybe you can read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/840501/2173917) to get some more insight.

Comment: Am I missing something? Isnt create_patchwork_value_fct a typedef, not the func ptr itself?

Comment: @DaanTimmer yep, I stand correted. Thanks to mjs, though. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This isnt actually a function pointer - this is defining a function pointer type:

`typedef struct patchwork *(*create_patchwork_value_fct) 
                                            (const enum nature_primitif);`

So, this defines a function pointer type called `create_patchwork_value_fct`. This is a function pointer to a function that takes a single parameter(const enum nature_primitif), and returns a `struct patchwork*` - i.e. a pointer to a patchwork struct.

Lets look at how this could be used:

```
void someFunc(create_patchwork_value_fct funcToCall, enum param)
{
    funcToCall(param);
}

struct patchwork* CreateAPatchworkValue(enum nature_primitif enumVal)
{
     struct patchwork* pwork = malloc(sizeof(struct patchwork));
     pwork->someVal = enumVal;
     return pwork;
}


void main()
{
    someFunc(CreateAPatchworkValue, <a valid nature_primitif enumeration value>)
}
```

in this example, `main()` calls `someFunc()`, passing it a pointer to CreateAPatchworkValue as the `funcToCall` parameter, and a value from the nature_primitif enum.

someFunc then calls funcToCall, which is actually a call to CreateAPatchworkValue.